# No: of ways to distribute cards .

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can a person send invitation cards to $6$ of his friends 
>   if he has $4$ servants to distribute the cards ?

$a.)\ 6^{4}\\
\color{green}{b.)\ 4^{6}}\\
c.)\ 24\\
d.)\ 120$

As the cards here are $6$ and the servants are $4$ so I thought there will be $6^{4}$ ways but the book gives answer as option $b.)$

I look for a short and simple way .

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.

Answer (score 4):

For each card you have to choose a servant to deliver it. There are 4 options to do so.

So there are 4 options for the first card, 4 options for the second card, and so on, until lastly there are 4 options for the sixth card. That's a total of $4\cdots4=4^6$ options.

Answer (score 3):

You were correct in that it is of the form:$$(\text{#options per choice})^{(\text{#times to choose them})}$$

You just muddled up identifying which was which.

Each and every of *six* friends must receive exactly one card, delivered by *one of four* servants   (Each of the servant *may* deliver anywhere from none up to six cards.)   That's choosing from *four* options *six* times.

We count : $4\times 4\times 4\times 4\times 4\times 4$ ways to assign a servant to each of the six cards. Thusly: $4^6$.

Answer (score 2):

Each one of the 6 friends can be served by each one of the 4 servants.  So:

1. The 1st friend can be served by each 1 of the 4 servants
2. The 2nd friend can be served by each 1 of the 4 servants
3. and so on... up to the 6th

So: $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 4^6$

If you'd notice, it is quite the same as the [binary counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_counting):
How many numbers in base 2 can be represented by 3 digits?
Well, there are 3 digits, each have 2 possible values of `1` or `0`, ergo there are $2^3 = 8$ possible values, starting from 0 up to 7 (including).

Answer (score 1):

You got the question wrong.

The question actually means in how many ways you can send your servants to send the cards.